How to Solve Partial Derivative with Summation (for Linear Regression)?
I'm demonstrating linear regression so I would like to calculate derivatives 1 & 2 using Mathematica, something like this

This is based on the textbook notation in Johnston's Econometric Methods ed. 3, p. 18

This is my demo so far.  It doesn't show the derivation of the normal equations.
data = {{1, 0.891}, {2, 0.885}, {3, 0.844}, {4, 0.836}, {5, 0.849}};
MapIndexed[(X[First@#2] = #1) &, First /@ data];
MapIndexed[(Y[First@#2] = #1) &, Last /@ data];
n = Length[data];
ΣX = Sum[X[i], {i, n}];
ΣY = Sum[Y[i], {i, n}];
ΣXY = Sum[X[i] Y[i], {i, n}];
ΣX2 = Sum[X[i]^2, {i, n}];
Clear[a, b]; sol = N@First@Solve[{
     (* Normal equations for straight line *)
     ΣY == n a + b ΣX,
     ΣXY == a ΣX + b ΣX2}, {a, b}]


{a -> 0.9009, b -> -0.0133}

I'd also like to relate the above to the linear algebra method, but I doubt there's a simple way.
{x, y} = Transpose[data];
X = Map[{1, #} &, x];
{a, b} = Inverse[Transpose[X].X].Transpose[X].y


{0.9009, -0.0133}


In version 14.1, the answer is yes, to some degree :) . We just need to turn to the vector notation:
Y = VectorSymbol["Y", n];
X = VectorSymbol["X", n];

e = (Y - a SymbolicOnesArray[{n}] - b X);

eq1 = D[e . e, a] == 0 // TensorExpand // Simplify
(* a SymbolicOnesArray[{n}] . SymbolicOnesArray[{n}] + 
   b SymbolicOnesArray[{n}] . VectorSymbol["X", n] == 
   SymbolicOnesArray[{n}] . VectorSymbol["Y", n] *)


eq2 = D[e . e, b] == 0 // TensorExpand // Simplify

(* a SymbolicOnesArray[{n}] . VectorSymbol["X", n] + 
  b VectorSymbol["X", n] . VectorSymbol["X", n] == 
   VectorSymbol["X", n] . VectorSymbol["Y", n] *)


Further, we can obtain outputs using the summation notation by defining some replacement rules:
rule = {VectorSymbol[a_, n_] . 
          VectorSymbol[b_, n_] :> Inactive[Sum][Subscript[a, i] Subscript[b, i], i],
        SymbolicOnesArray[{n_}] . VectorSymbol[a_, n_] :> 
          Inactive[Sum][Subscript[a, i], i], 
        SymbolicOnesArray[{n_}] . SymbolicOnesArray[{n_}] :> n};

eq1 /. rule


eq2 /. rule


